# Find the number of cases per location and categorize the count with respect to reason for taking loan

Tags: sql, hadoop, hiveql

input

```
+---------+--------------------+-----------+
|   id    |       reason       | location  |
+---------+--------------------+-----------+
| 1077501 | credit_card        | AZ        |
| 1077430 | car                | GA        |
| 1077175 | small_business     | IL        |
| 1076863 | other              | CA        |
| 1075358 | other              | OR        |
| 1075269 | wedding            | AZ        |
| 1069639 | debt_consolidation | NC        |
| 1072053 | car                | CA        |
| 1071795 | small_busines      | CA        |
+---------+--------------------+-----------+
```

output should be

```
+----------+-------------+-----+----------------+----------+---------+-------+
| location | credit_card | car | small_business | other... | wedding | total |
+----------+-------------+-----+----------------+----------+---------+-------+
| AZ       |           1 |   0 |              0 |        0 |       1 |     2 |
| CA       |           0 |   1 |              1 |        0 |       0 |     2 |
+----------+-------------+-----+----------------+----------+---------+-------+
```

output should be in above format reason for each location as a column.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  This is kinda basic stuff should not be hard.

Comment: yes i have tried but reason cloumn value  should be dynamically converted to column i can do only for few values.       .

Comment: The Answer below works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot with Dynamic columns

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
   + QUOTENAME(reason)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT reason FROM #T) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT location, ' + @ColumnName +',Total = ' + REPLACE(@ColumnName,',[', ' + [') +'
FROM #T
PIVOT(count(Id) 
      FOR reason IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```